# Intermittent error with Google Visualization within App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sheets

I'm getting now infrequently an error when creating a Google Chart within Google App Script.

The code bellow creates a blob, but, in 25% of the time, the image contains a banner with this error:

```
'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'b.G()')
```

I'm familiar with this error in the JS/HTML world, and it usually indicates that the data was not loaded at the time the chart object was created.

The App Script code is as follow and run correctly in roughly 75% of the time:

```
  // Get data for chart
  var dataTable = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
     .getSheetByName("Chart_Data")
     .getRange("A1:F91")
     .getDataTable(true);

  // Wait 3 seconds and flush any activity
  Utilities.sleep(3000);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();   

  // Test if data object is empty
  if (dataTable==null) {
    Logger.log("Error, dataTable is null");  
  }

  // Create Line Chart Builder
  var lineChart = Charts.newLineChart()
    .setTitle('Weekly Activations by product line (7 days rolling)')
    .setLegendPosition(Charts.Position.RIGHT)
    .setDimensions(600, 400)
    .setDataTable(dataTable)
    .setColors(["blue","DarkGreen","DarkRed","#eec","#cee"]);

  // Wait 3 seconds and flush any activity
  Utilities.sleep(3000);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();    

  // Test if chart builder object is empty
  if (lineChart==null) {
    Logger.log("Error, lineChart is null");  
  }  

  // Build chart
  var chart = lineChart.build();  

  // Wait 3 seconds and flush any activity
  Utilities.sleep(3000);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();    

  // Test if chart object is empty
  if (chart==null) {
    Logger.log("Error, chart is null");  
  }  

  // Convert chart to image blob
  var chart1Blob = chart.getAs('image/jpeg'); //get chart as image

  // Wait 3 seconds and flush any activity
  Utilities.sleep(3000);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();    

  // Test if chart image is empty
  if (chart1Blob==null) {
    Logger.log("Error, chart1Blob is null");  
  }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you still facing this problem? Or were you able to have this resolved in some other way?